# Express & Multer not uploading file single/any resulting in req.file/req.files undefined or []

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload, multer

This issue has me stumped. My app requires uploading an excel file with content to add/modify, etc on the platform. For this, I need Multer to upload the excel file where I will store it in `os.tempdir()` for reading.

**Problem:**

Using the suggested methods and alternatives, I am unable to upload a file via the browser to my app (running locally). I have tried methods using [.single("input file name here")](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#singlefieldname) which places the file in `req.file`, or [any()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#any) which places the file(s) in `req.files`. Non of these return a successful file upload, thus `req.file` is always `undefined` and `req.files` is always `[]`.

**What code do I have?**

Below you will find my webpage & server side code:

**Web-page (jade)**

```
...
form(action=`/companies/${companyId}/employees/upload` enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post")
    input(type="file", accept=".xlsx,.xls" , name="uploadEmployees", style="background: transparent" required)
    input(type="hidden" name="test" value="test")
    button#submitUpload.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Save changes
...
```

***Notes:***

- `companyId` is defined in my jade template, thus the action URL is complete and correct
- the `enctype` type is correct, one should [always use multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/4628115) for file uploads
- the method is correct, I am posting data
- the `input` field with `type=file` MUST have a name attribute, this as you will see is correctly specified in my `multer.single("name here")` server side code.
- the `hidden` `input` field with `name=test` I added as a sanity check, this field doesn't show in `req`

**Server-side Code:**

```
const multer = require('multer')
const uploadSpreadsheet = multer().any();

// router prefix is /companies
router.post('/:id/employees/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    uploadSpreadsheet(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            console.log("Multer error")
            console.error(err);
        } else if (err) {
            console.log("Another error")
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log("Multer function success, next()")
            next()
        }
    });
}, async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Using multer.any()")
    console.log("req.files should not be empty")
    console.log(`${req.files ? (req.files.length > 0 ? "req.files has some files" : "req.files has no files") : "req.files is undefined"}`)
    console.log(`We should expect to find a hidden field named 'test' with value 'test'`)
    console.log(`${req.body === {} ? "req.body is empty" : req.body["test"] ? "hidden field found" : "no hidden field named 'test' found"}`)
    console.log(req.body);
    if (!req.file || req.file === "") {
        req.flash("message", [{
            status: false,
            message: "No file uploaded or upload failed"
        }]);
        return res.redirect(`/companies/${req.params.id}/employees`)
    }

    // read the entire file
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile(req.file);
    ...
```

***Notes:***

- in an attempt to check Multer errors, I used the Multer error handling as suggested [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling) - see the `uploadSpreadsheet(req, res...)` part above. This always goes `next()` w/o any errors.
- when hitting `req.file || req.file === ""`, it always fails and redirects. `req.file` and `req.files` is always either undefined or `[]` respectively.

**Console output:**

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-app"
>  Multer function success, next()
>  Using multer.any()
>  req.files should not be empty
>  req.files has no files
>  We should expect to find a hidden field named 'test' with value 'test'
>  no hidden field named 'test' found
>  [Object: null prototype] {}
```

Since the line `Multer function success, next()` appears, one should expect to find file(s) either in `req.files` or `req.file` but this doesn't happen.

**Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!**

---

**Multer single file upload (for completeness sake)**

I define my single file upload function & parameters below:

```
const os = require('os')
const tmp = os.tmpdir();

function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    // for testing
    cb(null, true);
}

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${tmp}`)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, v4())
    }
})
// const uploadSpreadsheet = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter}).single("uploadEmployees");
```

in the post route, this is what it looks like when using my single file upload:

```
router.post('/:id/employees/upload', uploadSpreadsheet, async (req, res, next) => {
    ...
```

client side code remains constant through these above server-side code changes